# Modelling interactions with only a subset of the levels of a factor in R

Tags: regression, interaction

Let's first look at `lm`. I have a continuous explanatory $X$ and a factor $F$ modelling seasonal aspects (in the example 8 levels).

Let $\beta$ denote the slope for $X$ then I want to model interactions of the slope with the factor. It is some kind of physical model thus I an assume that the interaction is significant only for 2 of the 8 levels.
How can this be formulated? I would like to use an ordinary formula as later I would like to put it into a censored regression in the `AER` package (function `tobit`)

The data is:

```
N = 50
f = rep(c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"),N)
fcoeff = rep(c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-5,-10,-5),N)
beta = rep(c(5,5,5,8,4,5,5,5),N)
set.seed(100) 
x = rnorm(8*N)+1
epsilon = rnorm(8*N,sd = sqrt(1/5))
y = x*beta+fcoeff+epsilon
```

A fit with all interactions gives an accurate result

```
fit <- lm(y~0+x+x*f)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x + x * f)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.41018 -0.30296  0.01818  0.32657  1.20677 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
x      5.039064   0.075818   66.463   <2e-16 ***
fs1   -0.945112   0.088072  -10.731   <2e-16 ***
fs2   -2.107483   0.103590  -20.344   <2e-16 ***
fs3   -2.992401   0.088164  -33.941   <2e-16 ***
fs4   -4.054411   0.094878  -42.733   <2e-16 ***
fs5   -2.730448   0.094815  -28.798   <2e-16 ***
fs6   -5.232721   0.102254  -51.174   <2e-16 ***
fs7   -9.969175   0.096307 -103.515   <2e-16 ***
fs8   -4.922782   0.092917  -52.980   <2e-16 ***
x:fs2 -0.006081   0.097748   -0.062    0.950    
x:fs3 -0.050684   0.102124   -0.496    0.620    
x:fs4  2.988702   0.103652   28.834   <2e-16 ***
x:fs5 -1.196775   0.105139  -11.383   <2e-16 ***
x:fs6  0.099112   0.103811    0.955    0.340    
x:fs7 -0.007648   0.110908   -0.069    0.945    
x:fs8 -0.107148   0.094346   -1.136    0.257    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4705 on 384 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9942,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.994 
F-statistic:  4120 on 16 and 384 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

How can I model the interaction with `s4` and `s5` only? Can I delete the other interactions from the fit for further predictions?

I tried to split the factors in 2 but then the model gets singular:

```
f = rep(c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"),N)
fcoeff = rep(c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-5,-10,-5),N)
f2 = rep(c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"),N)
f[f %in% c("s4","s5")] <- "no.inter"
f2[f2 %in% c("s1","s2","s3","s6","s7","s8")] <- "rest"

fit <- lm(y~0+x+x*f2+ f)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x + x * f2 + f)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.41018 -0.31544  0.00653  0.31615  1.20670 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x       5.01794    0.02756 182.106   <2e-16 ***
f2rest -5.02213    0.07381 -68.045   <2e-16 ***
f2s4   -4.05441    0.09495 -42.702   <2e-16 ***
f2s5   -2.73045    0.09488 -28.777   <2e-16 ***
fs1     4.09310    0.09480  43.177   <2e-16 ***
fs2     2.93401    0.09424  31.132   <2e-16 ***
fs3     2.00475    0.09456  21.201   <2e-16 ***
fs6    -0.07894    0.09419  -0.838    0.402    
fs7    -4.93545    0.09452 -52.213   <2e-16 ***
fs8          NA         NA      NA       NA    
x:f2s4  3.00983    0.07591  39.651   <2e-16 ***
x:f2s5 -1.17565    0.07793 -15.086   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4709 on 389 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9941,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.994 
F-statistic:  5983 on 11 and 389 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to manipulate the model matrix to remove the unwanted columns:

```
xx <- model.matrix(y ~ 0 + x + x*f)
omit <- grep("[:]fs[^45]", colnames(xx))
xx <- xx[, -omit]
lm(y ~ 0 + xx)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + xx)

Coefficients:
    xxx    xxfs1    xxfs2    xxfs3    xxfs4    xxfs5    xxfs6    xxfs7    xxfs8  xxx:fs4  xxx:fs5  
  5.018   -0.929   -2.088   -3.017   -4.054   -2.730   -5.101   -9.958   -5.022    3.010   -1.176
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. It works perfectly for the example. Now I have to adapt it to the real world example.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to handle a prediction with all the new column names? new.data = data.frame(x,f) and then predict(fit,new.data) would not work correctly, right?

Comment: Perhaps the best approach is to create the prediction dataframe in the same way you create the model dataframe: that is, fill a dataframe with the desired values, create a model matrix for it, and use that as the argument to your `predict` function. I haven't tested this. I can recommend you do all your testing with `tobit` rather than `lm`, because I have found that the various versions of `predict` can be idiosyncratic and difficult to use. You might as well focus on learning how to use the version you ultimately need.

Comment: new.data = data.frame(x,f)
new.data.matrix = model.matrix( ~ 0 + x + x*f)
omit <- grep("[:]fs[^45]", colnames(new.data.matrix))
new.data.matrix <- new.data.matrix[, -omit]
pred = predict(fit,data.frame(new.data.matrix))
this seems to work! Sorry that I can not properly edit the comment

Answer (score 6):

The R aspects of this question are off topic, but the statistical aspects are on topic.

If I may summarize:  You want to model an interaction between a continuous variable and a categorical one, but only at certain levels of the categorical one.

I don't think you can do this in a linear model, at least, not directly.  You could, however, subset the data by level of the categorical variable and then include the interaction only in certain subsets. Another possibility is some form of regression tree, which may wind up with nodes being split into levels of the categorical variable - but I do not know of a method for forcing certain interactions into the tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your summary is correct. I will think whether I can subset the data. I assume that I will lose the nice property of the common base level of the slope. It has a clear interpretation in my application.

Comment: Yes, I think you will lose that.  I would only do this if there is a strong reason to force the interaction at the other levels of the categorical variable to be 0.